# Unit testing Reader build by JsonItemReaderBuilder

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a class which contains Beans used in a Batch Job:

```
@Configuration
public class JobBeans { 
    @Bean
    JsonItemReader<Rabbit> jsonReader() {
        return new JsonItemReaderBuilder<Rabbit>()
            .jsonObjectReader(new JacksonJsonObjectReader<>(Rabbit.class))
            .resource(new ClassPathResource("rabbits.json"))
            .name("rabbitReader")
            .build();
    }
}
```

How can I test Beans like this?

My current Test Suite looks like that:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = JobBeans.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, StepScopeTestExecutionListener.class })
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class RabbitReaderTest {

    @Autowired
    private JsonItemReader<Rabbit> sut;

    @Test
    public void read() throws Exception {
        assertNotNull(sut.read());
    }
}
```

It throws a NPE during test execution:

> 10:40:07.684 [Thread-0] WARN
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter -
>   Invocation of destroy method 'close' failed on bean with name
>   'rabbitReader'
>   org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Error while
>   closing item reader   at
>   org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.close(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:138)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.invokeCustomDestroyMethod(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:364)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:287)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1033)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1009)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$2.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:928)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null   at
>   org.springframework.batch.item.json.JacksonJsonObjectReader.close(JacksonJsonObjectReader.java:89)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.item.json.JsonItemReader.doClose(JsonItemReader.java:123)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.close(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:135)
>     ... 14 common frames omitted

It appears that the InputStream is null even though the file is provided in the test resources directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `close` method of your reader is called but not the `open` method. You need to open the reader before using it to read data. For example:

```
@Test
public void read() throws Exception {
    sut.open(new ExecutionContext());
    assertNotNull(sut.read());
    sut.close();
}
```

Comment: Ty for your help! Unfortunately it still produces the same NPE.

Comment: Where is the `close` method called in your test?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at org.springframework.batch.item.json.JacksonJsonObjectReader.close(JacksonJsonObjectReader.java:89)
 at org.springframework.batch.item.json.JsonItemReader.doClose(JsonItemReader.java:123)
 at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.close(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:135)

Comment: I mean who is calling this method? only the `read` method is called in your unit test.  Do you have a `@After` method that is closing the reader?

Comment: No I dont have a @After. It seems to be called during the read() or after the tests are executed.

Comment: The `read` method does not call `close`. It should be called somewhere after your test. Please provide your full unit test configuration so I can help.

Comment: Im sry but this is my full test configuration so far. If I add @-Before and @-After methods to open/close the reader, the test passes but it still throws the NPE.

Comment: Thank you very much for ur help! I just realized that there are other readers in the JobBeans class which are created (and not properly opened/closed) when the test runs. That seems to be the case since the class is added with @ContextConfiguration(classes = JobBeans.class), which includes all Beans in this class. Can I include/exclude beans to prevent this behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do that since the `ContextConfiguration` annotation works at the class level. You can probably separate your beans or, since it is a unit test, just create the reader in the test method to test it in isolation.